# Live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments, ejs

I am working with Stripe.js and implementing all of that code from the server side. The server gives me an HTML-Js response and I render this in a mobile WebView. In test mode, all work fine but when I switched to live mode it gives me an error as mentioned below

```
1. Stripe.js requires 'allow-same-origin' if sandboxed    
2. Live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS
```

Error 1 is also received while using Test Mode but at that time I am able to make a redirect to the checkout page but error 2 is only received in Live Mode, the interesting thing is **I am already making requests from HTTPS.**

The confusing thing is It works well with mobile browsers like Chrome and Safari but not with WebView.

My server is configured with an SSL Certificate.

P.S. We are using the EJS template engine to render HTML from the server side.

Comment: What WebView are you using specifically? Ie in iOS there are WKWebView or UIWebView.
In the end of the day, I would recommend reaching out to Stripe Support and give them your public accessible URL.

Comment: @Hemal have you implemented stripe on flutter web also ?

Comment: Nope but I belive app and web both follow the same process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the one in the error from the console — I can't use stripe.js on a page that does not use HTTPS. What probably happens is evaluating the response from my server and rendering the webview is not a 'real' web page it's some template I am render in an iframe, and the browser's URL is "about:blank".

I have added baseUrl in webview

```
          InAppWebView(
            initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
              data: resposne,
              baseUrl: Uri.parse('https://whatever.com'),
            ),
```

If I don't pass baseUrl then system got the URL "about:blank" and that's not valid. Stripe only accept HTTPS url